# MVC Validation on Model in Portable Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC but have worked my way through the validation tutorials and they do exactly what I want to do... but.... my model is in a separate portable class library.

How would I add the validation rules to this non-MVC solution so that my MVC website?

Is it possible please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface to that class and use impromptu interface to have your class act as that interface...

Lets say this is the class from the portable library:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Create a cloned interface and specify validation attributes in it:

```
public interface ISomeClass
{
    [Required]
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

At the top of your view, pass the interface instead of the class:

```
@model YourNamespace.Models.ISomeClass
```

In your controller, do:

```
return View(instanceOfSomeClass.ActLike<ISomeClass>();
```

You can find impromptu interface here:
http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/

Since the class and the interface look exactly the same, model binding works as well.

Hope this helps.